# Flex mobile - IconItemRenderer - Move icon to other container

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, air, flex-mobile

I'm trying to customize the IconItemRenderer. The result should look like the windows icons (icon at the top, label at the bottom) but under the icon should be a white square with drop shadow filter. The icon should be centered in it (icon's can be different size but not larger than the square).
I can't manage to remove the iconDisplay symbol and add it to another container that's on top of the white square.

Comment: I'd extend the IconItemRenderer class and position things differently. I think you want to look at the layoutContents() method.  If not there, check updateDisplayList()

Comment: Yes, i have extended the IconItemRenderer. I can't manage to do nothing in layoutContents(), createChildren() and updateDisplayList().
Can somebody please show me link with code example or something like that. The iconDisplay just can be removed properly from the class.

Comment: How about you show us what you've done and we can help from there?  Here are some articles I've written: https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/6/23/Understanding-Mobile-itemRenderers and https://www.flextras.com/blog/index.cfm/2011/6/24/Building-a-Mobile-ItemRenderer-in-Flex .  At the bottom of each post, there is a "Related Posts" section where you can find some more information.

Comment: Ok, in the IconItemRenderer i have instance of UIComponent called thumbBgr, I can't manage to place the iconDisplay on top of the thumbBgr. I hope it's clear now. Nice tutorials but I don't find them related to my problem.